# Why is this suppression of all but one integer value not working?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read in a list of numbers from a file in C. I only want to capture the very first integer in the file and skip EVERYTHING else. I'm using C99.

This is what I have but it is not working.

```
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    int input;

    int i = 0;
    while( fscanf(file,"%d%*d", &input ) != EOF); ..................
```

Shouldn't the %*d suppress all following integers?
I think I'm on the right track but I'm not understanding something.

Comment: If you just want to read the first integer, couldn't you just skip the `while` loop entirely and just call `fscanf` exactly once?

Comment: @templatetypedef: What if the list of numbers isn't at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @CareyGregory: then you have to read byte by byte to get to a point where you have a digit, possibly preceded by a sign.  Fiddly, but far from impossible to implement.

Comment: @templatetypedef that does exactly what I needed! you should answer so I can give you credit

Comment: @lampShade: My answer also does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
int found = 0;
char buffer[100];
while (fgets(buffer, 100, file))
{
    if (!found && sscanf(&input, "%d", buffer) == 1)
       found = 1;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just drop the found flag and change found = 1 to a break statement.  But not sure if you need to read the entire file for some reason so coded it with the flag.